# Switch website language JS/JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, undefined, multilingual

I'm building a website and here is basically what I want to achieve using JavaScript:

if browser language = fr then get the text from languageFr.json
else get the text from languageEn.json

Here is what my code looks like for now:

My JSON

```
{
"h2": "random title",
    "p": lorem ipsum
}
```

My JavaScript, in the head of index.html

```
<script text="text/javascript">
    var lang;

    function detect() {
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        if (userLang == "fr") {
             lang = JSON.parse("languageFr.json");
        } else {
                 lang = JSON.parse("languageEn.json");
        }       
    }

    $(document).ready(detect());
</script>
```

And then in my HTML's body:

```
<h2><script>document.write(lang.h2);</script></h2>
```

However this does not seem to work. Chrome's console tells me lang is undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You need to retrieve the language file at first with an AJAX call (or load them directly).

Answer (score 3):

1. The code `<h2><script>document.write(lang.h2);</script></h2>` executes before document ready. That's why your `detect` method has bot been called at the moment and `lang` has not been initialized.
2. You use JSON.parse method in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thought is that the Javascript in this block

```
<h2><script>document.write(lang.h2);</script></h2>
```

is executing before the function has run.

That Javascript will execute as soon as the browser reaches it; the browser will pause parsing the page to do this. However, your detect function looks like it's waiting for the document ready event to run.

So, the document.write() call happens before the detect() method is called, and lang has no value.

Answer (score 0):

Egor4eg is correct about the problem (actually most of the answers are). I'd advise you to use a different method for filling in any elements that should have language-specific text. Here's a possibility.

```
<div class="i18nstring" data-message="h2"></div>

//Put this at the bottom of your detect() function (so it's only called after $ ready)

$('.i18nstring').forEach(function() {
    $(this).text( lang[this.dataset.message] );
}
```

That might need just a little bit more work (mostly on the data-message thing) to be fully cross-browser compatible, but JQuery can help with that. Note that each i18nstring node does not have to be a div.